# Calculation of limit with sandwich theorem

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

I want to calculate the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n^2+n+1}$$ I have done the following :

$$\left |\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n^2+n+1}\right |=\frac{|n+\sin(n)|}{|n^2+n+1|}=\frac{|n+\sin(n)|}{n^2+n+1}\leq \frac{|n|+|\sin(n)|}{n^2+n+1}=\frac{n+|\sin(n)|}{n^2+n+1}\leq \frac{n+n}{n^2+n+1}=\frac{2n}{n^2+n+1}\leq \frac{2n}{n^2}=\frac{2}{n}$$ So since $\left |\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n^2+n+1}\right |\leq \frac{2}{n}$ we get $$-\frac{2}{n}\leq \frac{n+\sin(n)}{n^2+n+1}\leq \frac{2}{n}$$ and since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left (-\frac{2}{n}\right )=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left (\frac{2}{n}\right )=0$ and so we get $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n+\sin(n)}{n^2+n+1}=0$.

Is this correct? Or could we get an other easier inequality to use the sandwich theorem?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Ok! Thank you!  :-) @GuyFsone